# error message "ubuntu-20.04-desktop no mountable file systems"

Tags: software-installation

Trying to install on an old Mac "2009" OS 10.6.8 and still get the error message after reading the previous replies and trying to download latest version. Please help

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and was able to solve it easily when I realized 1 thing:

You know when you download and you get the dialog box which has you choose to either open the file or save it?

I only got the "no mountable file systems" message when I chose to *open* the file.

Try downloading again, but this time choose "**Save**."

Hopefully this will work for you too!

Also, this YouTube video does a great job of walking you through it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04ZNAKmm0dI